# yii2 криво получается передать ассоциативный массив параметром в Url::to

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть массив $array

```
Array
(
    [gender] => 2
    [cat_id] => 1
)
```

передавая его параметром в `Url::to(['catalog/', $array])`

получаю в урле кракозябры `/catalog?1%5Bgender%5D=2&1%5Bcat_id%5D=1`

подскажите плиз, как правильно передать массив, чтобы был урл без лишних символов?

Comment: Что-то я в доках не нашел метода, где можно вложенный массив передать...... должно быть вроде `Url::to(['catalog/', 'param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2'])` .... судя по http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html#creating-urls  ........ т.е. `'param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2'` это не вложенный массив, это ключ значения текущего массива

Comment: а не знаете как преобразовать ассоциативный массив в такую строку вида 'param1' => 'value1' , есть ли стандартные функции (я найти не смог)?

Comment: можно попробовать воспользоваться `php` функцией [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php) `$url = ['catalog/'];
$params = ['gender' => 2, 'cat_id' => 1]; Url::to(array_merge($url, $params));` или `Url::to(array_merge(['catalog/'], $params));`

Comment: сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен в комментариях, но я все-равно напишу ответ, т.к. это может быть кому-то еще полезно.

Метод [`Url::to()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail) может принимать в качестве первого параметра либо строку с роутом, либо массив, в котором первым элементом будет все та же строка с роутом, а остальные элементы -- параметры запроса в формате *ключ->значение*.

Т.е. правильный вызов будет выглядеть вот так:

```
Url::to([
    'catalog',
    'gender' => 2,
    'cat_id' => 1
]);
```

Эта конструкция должна выдать в url вида `/catatolg?gender=2&cat_id=1`.

В вопросе же параметры вызова вглядят следующи образом `*`:

```
Url::to([
    // не нужно в конце писать `/`
    0 => 'catalog/', 
    // параметр - массив
    1 => [ 
        'gender' => 2,
        'cat_id' => 1
    ]
]);
```

Что выдает url вида: `/catalog?' . urlencode('1[gender]=2&1[cat_id]=1')`

`*` учитывая что в PHP все массивы на самом деле ассоциативные, просто когда ключи не указываются явно, то подразумевается что ключи -- целочисленные индексы 0, 1, 2...

Comment: спасибо за полезный комментарий!

Answer (score 0):

у меня так сработало:

```
Url::to([
            'create',
            'id' => $id,
            'params[p1]' => 1,
            'params[p2]' => 2
        ])

  public function actionCreate($id) {
    $params = [];
    if (!empty(Yii::$app->request->get('params'))) {
        $params = Yii::$app->request->get('params');
    }
```